# Selenium Webdriver: Entering text into text field -element not visible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to enter text (111) into text fields and I have tried nearly all element locators, Javascript tricks and the text just does not get entered into the fields.

i tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='input-wrapper icon wupid']")).sendKeys("111");
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

the html code:

```
<form id="form-resetpass" method="post" action="" _lpchecked="1">
<div class="input-wrapper icon wupid">
<label for="wupid">תעודת זהות</label>
<input class="only-numbers ltr" type="text" value="" maxlength="9" name="wupid" style="background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAASCAYAAABSO15qAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAPhJREFUOBHlU70KgzAQPlMhEvoQTg6OPoOjT+JWOnRqkUKHgqWP4OQbOPokTk6OTkVULNSLVc62oJmbIdzd95NcuGjX2/3YVI/Ts+t0WLE2ut5xsQ0O+90F6UxFjAI8qNcEGONia08e6MNONYwCS7EQAizLmtGUDEzTBNd1fxsYhjEBnHPQNG3KKTYV34F8ec/zwHEciOMYyrIE3/ehKAqIoggo9inGXKmFXwbyBkmSQJqmUNe15IRhCG3byphitm1/eUzDM4qR0TTNjEixGdAnSi3keS5vSk2UDKqqgizLqB4YzvassiKhGtZ/jDMtLOnHz7TE+yf8BaDZXA509yeBAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: left center;">
</div>
```

why i cant enter the value ?

Comment: Your driver is faster than your rendering engine. You need to wait until the item is loaded (i.e. it's visible) and then you can access it. Also note that just because it's visible in the html, it may be hidden from the css.

Answer (score 3):

You can use wait concept for this.

Implicit Wait:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

or 
you use explicit wait + expected condition:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("someid")));
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: thank you for your answer but after i add Implicit Wait i got an error:

_Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //div[@class='input-wrapper icon wupid']_

this is not solve the problem

Comment: First check whether xpath is valid or not, you can verify in Firefox.

Comment: To get stability in your framework you should use explicit wait.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code.Please not that it is in C#, please convert it into java format.

```
WebDriverWait mywait = new WebDriverWait(driver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
IWebElement txtbox = mywait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By....));
txtbox.SendKeys("111");
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your html code, there is text field in the input tag only. So you can use this xpath : "//input[@class='only-numbers ltr']" and use explicit wait.